# Authenticate Teamcity against LDAP using StartTLS

Tags: linux, debian, openldap, teamcity

I am running a 6.5 version of Teamcity on a Debian Squeeze server and I use OpenLDAP to authenticate users.

I know I can use LDAPS to be able to use encrypted password authentication, however this has been deprecated by the OpenLDAP developers, see: http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/605.html

I would like to know if there is a way to configure LDAP authentication in Teamcity to use StartTLS on port 389.

I can't find anything about it here: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/LDAP+Integration
Or here: http://therightstuff.de/2009/02/02/How-To-Set-Up-Secure-LDAP-Authentication-With-TeamCity.aspx

Comment: I think this is in fact not yet possible with teamcity, probably should contact the developers.

Comment: Newest 7.0.1 version also doesn't seem to support it. I reported it to the developers.

Comment: I've tried to edit your question, but it seems the edit was rejected. Like many, you're confused about the difference between SSL and TLS. This is about LDAPS v.s. LDAP+StartTLS, not SSL v.s. TLS, see http://serverfault.com/a/368574/47187

Comment: Ok, this is a problem of correctly naming things, I approved your edit, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a bug report at teamcity's bug tracking system which was assigned to a developer. Indicating this is a feature not yet implemented in teamcity.

Therefore, to answer the question, currently it is not possible to configure LDAP authentication in Teamcity using StartTLS on port 389.